# Meteor ES6 fat arrow function and `this` in onCreated not working

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6

Sorry, ES6 newb here:

```
Template.hello.onCreated( () => {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  counter() {
    return Template.instance().counter.get();
  },
});

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
  },
});
```

When I click on the button I get `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

But when I do

```
Template.hello.onCreated( function(){
  // counter starts at 0
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});
```

it works fine.

So there's something going on with ES6's fat arrow binding of the `this` keyword that I'm not getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Meteor calls the `onCreated` handler, it binds the function's `this` value to the template instance. [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) *lexically* bind `this`, which means that `this` inside an arrow function is the same as where the function is defined, in your case probably `window`. As a result, you are creating a global variable `counter` instead of assigning it to the template instance.

For `onCreated`, `onRendered`, etc., it makes no sense to use arrow functions.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that arrow functions were the way *all* functions would need to be written in ES6 going forward? Does this mean in ES6 you actually need to think about which type of function to use especially if you're using `this`? BTW `counter` was indeed created as a global variable.

Comment: Exactly, both types of functions have their own use cases. Sometimes it doesn't matter which one you choose but callbacks for which the `this` context is provided by a framework (like `onCreated`) are one example where "normal" functions are necessary. Here is a nice article that lists some other cases: https://rainsoft.io/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/. In my projects, I always use `function`s unless arrow functions make the code easier to read.

Comment: Ohhhhhh.... thank you. Super valuable info here.